# Viewshed analysis with mutliple observers in ArcGIS Modelbuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, viewshed, visibility

I want to perform a viewshed analysis using multiple obeservation points. Each observation point has an observer height of 1.7 m and a buffer visibility distance of 5 km. In order to generate a buffer of 5 km I populated the my testpoint dataset with an attribute table RADIUS2 with 5000 meter, corresponding to the buffer viewshed limit. I used ArcGIS 10 to build a model builder that fairly does what I want. See Figure 1.
[image]

I tested the model by using three points: Point 1&2 in proximity of each other and therefore generating visibility value of 2. Then I generated a third point at distance bigger 5 km from the other two points in order to check if visibility buffer of 5 km in my model works. As you can see from figure 2 is does not, because point 3 should have value of 1 (blue), instead it is still influenced by the viewshed of point 1&2. Can somebody help me figure out what is wrong in my modelbuilder?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you have specified you are using ArcGIS 10.0 but not which build version then a simple search using google has thrown up this [list of issues](http://gisupdates.esri.com/10sp5/ArcGIS/ArcGIS10sp5-issues.htm) fixed by the service Pack 5. Viewshed radius being one of them. I suggest you install service pack 5 or upgrade your version of ArcGIS.